# Is the phrase "in individuals already anxious" correct in the following sentence?

Tags: adjectives, phrases

Is the following sentence correct with the phrase "in individuals already anxious"?
I meant to say a negatively perceived event by individuals who are already anxious would give rise to state anxiety.

> That is, their emotional state influences perceptions, so a negatively perceived/appraised workplace event/environment **in individuals already anxious** would give rise to more state anxiety.

would it be better to say "so a negatively perceived/appraised workplace event/environment **in individuals who are already anxious** would give rise to more state anxiety"

Comment: Both are fine. The **who are** is well understood.  Compare **in people seen in the street**. You don't need to insert **who are**. But as the situations (workplace event environment don't occur **in individuals**, I'd far prefer **in the case/instance of individuals.**

Comment: You might make the whole sentence clearer by moving **in individuals who are already anxious** to the end, e.g. "so a negatively perceived/appraised workplace event/environment would give rise to more state anxiety in individuals who are already anxious".